# How to find lost test scores?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I took the GRE test in August and the test scores were sent to the respective universities before the registration opens. Now I am worried because the test scores are not attached to my profile.

Is it possible that they are in the trash bin right now? If not, should I contact the help desk or resend the scores?

Comment: Do not worry.  If ETS sent the scores, the universities have them.

Comment: If in doubt, perhaps you could ask one of the universities you have applied to; also, it couldn't hurt to contact the help desk.  I don't have personal experience with them, and thus can't say whether that would be fruitful.